# Connect Ubuntu server to Windows PC directly by LAN cable

Tags: windows, networking, ubuntu, router

I work in the data processing field which requires a lot of Computational power(CPU) and RAM.

I currently have 2 PC:

**Main PC (Windows) - Screen + GPU + Peripherals**

**Local Server (Ubuntu) - No Screen/GPU**

Both are connected to my router and i access the Server via putty. I work primarily on my Main PC and both are connected to my router wifi. I was wondering if there is a way i can connect both PC using a lan cable (on the motherboards) and have the server use the same internet on my main pc. I"m currently using samba to access the server files on my pc.

Basically - i want the server to be directly connected to my main pc without going through the router and back etc. I am hoping it will reduce some latency when sharing files, updating file etc.

**MAIN PC: ASUS X570 + 5800X**

**SERVER: MSI Z690 + I7 13900k**

If i connect both pc by lan cable, is it something simple to set this up?

Comment: *I am hoping it will reduce some latency when sharing files, updating file etc.* No, nothing to gain from what you want to do and they're already using the same internet or do you have different router, different ISPs, etc.? Unlikely. So what can improve the performance is having both connected by Ethernet, or just one. All in all, this is a X-Y problem.

Comment: If you're talking about improving latency between the PC and the server, then yes, a direct connection could help.

Comment: What will (should) happen when you connect a cable between the two is that both will automatically assign an APIPA (169.254.x.x) address to the interface. As long as you use those IP addresses in your connection attempts (and not the one handed out by your router) it should work and the traffic will go over that local connection.

Answer (score 2):

> If i connect both pc by lan cable, is it something simple to set this up?

1. Connect cable.
2. Manually configure Ethernet interfaces on both computers with IP addresses from a *different* subnet than the LAN subnet.

It's the same as connecting the computers through an Ethernet switch; neither any special setup nor any special cable is needed.

The only rule is that IP addressing of different subnets must not overlap, e.g. if the LAN is currently using 192.168.1.0/24, then the separate connection could be (for example) 192.168.2.0/24 or 192.168.7.0/30. (It is typical for direct point-to-point connections to use a /30 netmask.)

You might even be able to skip step 2 if you did not go out of your way to disable IPv6 (as IPv6 will always set up link-local addresses, which are enough to make mDNS "myserver.local" names work), and/or if both systems support automatic "APIPA" address assignment for IPv4 (e.g. on Windows you'll see an 169.254./16 address automatically show up, and *possibly* on Ubuntu as well) – but in general I would not recommend relying on this for long-term usage.

> i want the server to be directly connected to my main pc without going through the router and back etc. I am hoping it will reduce some latency when sharing files, updating file etc.

The problem isn't just that it's going through the router, but that it's going *through Wi-Fi*, and especially that it's going through Wi-Fi *twice.* This means your PC and your router have to take turns sending data, due to sharing the same radio channel (i.e. Wi-Fi is half-duplex bus, while modern Ethernet is full-duplex). For example, after your server sends some packets to the router, it has to *wait* while the router is forwarding those packets to your computer.

This wouldn't occur if only one Wi-Fi connection is involved; most likely, connecting *just* the server to your router through Ethernet would already reduce latency (and improve throughput) quite a bit.

(Also, maybe your server has "power saving" enabled for its Wi-Fi interface? That is very often the cause of ~100ms extra latency for connections inbound to the server.)

Connecting both machines through the router's built-in Ethernet switch (if you have spare ports) – or through an external switch – is also an option and shouldn't have latency problems at all, either. The router's CPU would not be involved in packet forwarding within the subnet, and latency added by a switch is barely 1ms compared to a direct Ethernet cable.

Comment: I think the Windows PC will never forward the packets from the Ubuntu server to the router (and back) when the Ubuntu server tries to access the internet. The OP said he wants the Ubuntu server to use the Windows PC's internet. So what you described will not work. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @zomega: The PC *could* do that, but it doesn't sound like that's what OP wants – they're trying to set up a faster connection between PC and server specifically, while presumably still using Wi-Fi for the server's Internet access. (But Windows does have routing capabilities, e.g. as part of "Internet Connection Sharing" that's been there since Win98; though I'd personally rather do the opposite and route through the Linux server instead.)

Comment: He wrote "and have the server use the same internet on my main pc". I understood he wants to share the internet connection from his Windows PC with his Ubuntu server. But I am not sure. Maybe the easiest way for him is to enable "Internet Connection Sharing" on the Windows PC and disable WiFi on the Ubuntu server. Because then the Ubuntu server has only 1 IP and 1 active interface.

Answer (score 1):

@user1686 has some really good points - start with that answer. If you can, start by connecting just the server directly to your router.

If that's not possible or not fast enough, go for the direct connection. As long as both computers will still be connected to WiFi, they will have internet access. Just make sure to use the LAN IPs rather than WiFi IPs for direct communication.

If you insist on disconnecting one of the computers from WiFi, you can use a Windows feature called Internet Connection Sharing. You can turn it on in network adapter's properties. It will automatically assign a static IP address to the LAN interface and enable DHCP server which will assign an IP to whatever is connected to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the Ubuntu server to use your Windows PC's internet (as you said) then the Windows PC has to work like a network switch. It has to forward all packets from the Ubuntu server to the router and the other way around. But Windows is a network client and not a network switch so I think this will not work. Maybe there are ways to configure Windows to work like this.

The easier way may be to make the Windows PC use the Ubuntu's internet but then you have to configure the Ubuntu server to act like a network switch.

A third option is to configure another subnet between the Ubuntu server and the Windows PC. While both are still connected to the router directly for internet access. This is perhaps the way you want to do it because it only requires a LAN cable.

If money is no problem then here is a very easy solution. It requires no configuration on the two computers at all.

Simply buy a WiFi repeater which has 2 LAN connectors:

[AVM FRITZ!Repeater 3000](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B07P296595) (older and cheaper)

[AVM FRITZ!Repeater 6000](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B092VWMBZ2) (newer and more expensive)

Disable WiFi on both machines and connect them to the repeater using a LAN cable. The traffic between the two machines will go through the cable.

It's also possible to buy a repeater with only one LAN connector plus a gigabit switch:

[AVM FRITZ!Repeater 2400](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B07XCRYSDT)

[Netgear gigabit switch GS308](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B07PTTX7MX)

Of course the suggested devices are only examples.